# How to disable spring eureka registry server dashboard UI only?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dashboard, netflix-eureka

How to disable spring eureka registry server dashboard UI only.
This could be VA issue. As we shows server information.

Can some one help on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it by adding below property in application.properties file

```
eureka.dashboard.enabled = false
```

OR alternatively by adding in application.yml like

```
eureka:
  dashboard:
    enabled: false
```